# Shortest way of firing a function on ready with jquery

Tags: jquery

This such a trivial question, I have this function...

```
galleryAjax();
```

And I would like to fire it on doc ready. But currently I am writing it like this...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   galleryAjax();
});
```

It just seems a little long hand and I am wondering if there is a shorted way of writing this.

Thanks
Josh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can directly pass a function to jQuery:

```
$(galleryAjax);
```

From the [`.ready` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent:
>
> ```
> $(document).ready(handler)
> $().ready(handler) (this is not recommended)
> $(handler)
> ```

Of course if you want to execute more functions on DOM ready, it makes sense to pass an anonymous function:

```
$(function() {
    galleryAjax();
    // other functions are called here
});
```

Comment: Thanks felix for break down. +1

Comment: Can't you simply place the `galleryAjax();` in a script tag at the end of the `<body>`-tag without even passing it to jQuery?

Comment: @insertusernamehere: Yes, you could do that too, if you have control over where the script is included.

Comment: "*[…] if you have control over where the script is included*" - good point here.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as simple as shown below

```
$(galleryAjax);
```

or

```
jQuery(galleryAjax);
```

$ can be simply used instead of jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function () {

  //your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple as that:

```
$(function() {
   galleryAjax();
});
```

Moreover i don't get the meaning of `function($){` that you wrote...

Comment: jQuery passes a reference to itself to the `ready` callback. If you use jQuery in `noConflict` mode you can still refer to jQuery with `$` by defining the first parameter of the callback as `$`.

Answer (score 0):

As documented in [**here**](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent:

```
$(document).ready(handler)
$().ready(handler) (this is not recommended)
$(handler);//May be this is what you are looking for
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the only shorthand that I know of.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    galleryAjax();
});
```